# Kohana 3.3 Routes where the name of a Controller and Directory are the same

Tags: php, routes, uri, kohana, kohana-3.3

How do I correctly setup routes in Kohana 3.3 where the name of my controller and directory are the same as in my example below?

```
/application/classes/Controller/Admin/Author.php
 - admin/author
 - admin/author/add
 - admin/author/edit

/application/classes/Controller/Admin/Author/Book.php
 - admin/author/book
 - admin/author/book/add
 - admin/author/book/edit
```

When using the following routes in the specified order, I'm only able to access ***admin/author{/action}***, but not ***admin/author/book{/action}***.

Reversing the routing order gives me access to ***admin/author/book{/action}***, but not ***admin/author{/action}***

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'Main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('admin/author', 'admin/author(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin/author',
        'controller' => 'Main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Route::set('admin-author', '<directory>/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))', array(
        'directory' => '(admin|admin/author)',
        'action'    => '(add|edit|delete|index)'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'author',
    ));
```

Also, you can try to check action with regex `^book` (not tested).

Another way is to use [Route filters](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#route-filters).

Answer (score 0):

you need to define for admin/author/book as well

```
Route::set('admin-author-book', 'admin/author(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin/author',
        'controller' => 'book',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
Route::set('admin-author-book', 'admin/author(/book(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin/author',
        'controller' => 'book',
        'action'     => 'index',
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing about routes: **Routes are matched in the order they are added**. Reversing the order of your routes was correct, but the problem is that your route `admin/author` also matches `admin/author{/action}`. What you could do: make the controller and action mandatory:

```php
// Does not match admin/author/add
Route::set('admin/author', 'admin/author/<controller>/<action>(/<id>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin/author',
    ));

Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'Main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

There are several approaches, another one would be to create a "whitelist" of controllers:

```
// Does not match admin/author/add
Route::set('admin/author', 'admin/author/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))',
    array(
        'controller' => '(book|another-controller)'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin/author',
    ));

Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'Main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```